# How to find a table is used in any procedure or function or view

Tags: mysql

I am using MySQL, in my database I have a table named `tbltest`.

I want to check where this table is used in my database.

For an example: I want to check if this table is used in any store procedure/function/view.

How can i check in MySQL.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

As per the MySQL [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/columns-table.html)

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME, DATA_TYPE, IS_NULLABLE, COLUMN_DEFAULT
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE table_name = 'tbltest'
```

In case, if you want to check only in stored procedure/ function / view, then you can join with `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES`

UPDATE:

[`ROUTINE_TYPE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/routines-table.html) will provide the type like procedure/function.

```
SELECT DISTINCT ROUTINE_NAME, ROUTINE_TYPE 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES
WHERE ROUTINE_DEFINITION LIKE '%tbltest%'
      -- AND ROUTINE_TYPE = 'PROCEDURE' -- to filter SPs only
```

To check in `VIEWS`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT TABLE_NAME AS Name, 'VIEW' AS Type 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEWS 
WHERE VIEW_DEFINITION LIKE '%view_name%'
```

Comment: The above doesn't give me the views, but `SELECT DISTINCT ROUTINE_NAME AS name, ROUTINE_TYPE AS type
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES
WHERE ROUTINE_DEFINITION LIKE '%mytable_or_view%'
UNION 
SELECT DISTINCT TABLE_NAME AS name, 'VIEW' AS type 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEWS 
WHERE VIEW_DEFINITION LIKE '%mytable_or_view%';` does.

Comment: if my routine has tbltest_demo, also will included using above query